# Error pattern output

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a shell script which writes sqlplus errors to a log with the following output. I only want to capture @DB with errors and redirect to output to a error log. any tips? :

```
@DB_1
ERROR-123
ORA-123
@DB_2
@DB_3
@DB_4
ERROR-2222
ORA-3333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use I/O Redirection for show all output:

```
script.sh 1>output.txt 2>&1
```

Regards